# Proving two claims about sets and functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let X,Y be sets, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Prove:

1. $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ for every $B\subset Y$. Intuitively I understand why's that, but how do I prove it with formality?
2. For every $B\subset Y$, $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$ if and only if $f$ is surjective. Same as #1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Idea for 1. : Take an element $y$ in $f(f^{-1}(B))$, you know it can be written $f(x)$, with $x$ in $f^{-1}(B)$. What can you say about $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f : X \rightarrow Y$, $x \in X$, $y \in Y$, $A \subset X$, and $B \subset Y$ assumed throughout, and using the definitions $$
\begin{align}
(0) & y \in f(A) \;\equiv\; \langle \exists x : x \in A : f(x) = y \rangle \\
(1) & x \in f^{-1}(B) \;\equiv\; f(x) \in B \\
\end{align}
$$ the simplest thing I see is to calculate which elements are in $f(f^{-1}(B))$, since that is the most complex expression in the question: for every $y$ and $B$, we have $$
\begin{align}
& y \in f(f^{-1}(B)) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand using definition (0)"} \\
& \langle \exists x : x \in f^{-1}(B) : f(x) = y \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand using definition (1)"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) \in B : f(x) = y \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: substitute $y$ for $f(x)$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : y \in B : f(x) = y \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify, allowed because expression $y \in B$ does not contain $x$"} \\
& y \in B \;\land\; \langle \exists x :: f(x) = y \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"make $x \in X$ explicit -- to prepare for use of definition (0)"} \\
& y \in B \;\land\; \langle \exists x : x \in X: f(x) = y \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce definition (0)"} \\
& y \in B \;\land\; y \in f(X) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\cap$"} \\
& y \in B \cap f(X) \\
\end{align}
$$  (For clarity I've left in a few trivial steps that one would normally skip.)  So by set extensionality we've calculated that $$
(*) \;\;\;\;\; f(f^{-1}(B)) \;=\; B \cap f(X)
$$  From this key insight, both parts of the question follow directly.  For the first part use $B \cap f(X) \subset B$ from set theory.  For the second part, surjectivity automatically falls out of the following calculation: $$
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall B :: f(f^{-1}(B)) = B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"using (*)"} \\
& \langle \forall B :: B \cap f(X) = B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"make range explicit; set theory"} \\
& \langle \forall B : B \subset Y : B \subset f(X) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set theory"} \\
& Y \subset f(X) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality -- so that we can use our definitions again"} \\
& \langle \forall y : y \in Y : y \in f(X) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce definition (0)"} \\
& \langle \forall y : y \in Y : \langle \exists x : x \in X: f(x) = y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of surjectivity"} \\
& f \textrm { is surjective} \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. Then there is a $u \in f^{-1}(B)$ such that $f(u) = x$.  Since $u \in f^{-1}(B)$, by definition, we must have that $f(u) \in B$.  But recall that $x = f(u)$, so $x \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definitions: $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}$ and $f(A)=\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}$.
Thus 
$$\begin{align}& y\in f(f^{-1}(B))\\\iff &y=f(x)\text{ for some }x\in f^{-1}(B)\\\iff &y=f(x)\text{ for some }x\text{ with }f(x)\in B\\
\implies&y\in B\end{align}$$

Assume $f$ is surjective and $B\subset Y$.
Then there exists (by surjectivity) some $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$ for every $y\in Y$, especially for every $y\in B$. This $x$ is in $ f^{-1}(B)$, thus showing that $y=f(x)\in f(f^{-1}(B))$.

On the other hand, assum ethat $f$ is not surjective, say $y\notin f(X)$. Then $f(f^{-1}(\{y\}))=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset\ne\{y\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I explain 1. formally? I struggle with it terribly.